# Bash script - How to find substring in all txt files in directory one by one and write a message for all positive findings

Tags: bash, shell, sh

This is what I'm asked to do.

Browse all text (regular / plain) files in the specified folder (the first parameter of the script) and look for the specified word in them (the second parameter of the script). If the file contains the specified word, write the message: "YES, the word $2 is in $file". Otherwise write: "NO, there is no word $2 in $file"

Here is what i came with so far:

```
#!/bin/bash
FILES=$1
for file in $FILES
do
if [ $file == "*$2*" ];then
echo "YES, the word $2 is in $file"
else
echo "NO, there is no word $2 in $file"
fi
done
```

Comment: What did you already try? In which way did it fail? What tools did you find when you researched this task, and why were you unable to use them?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please be aware that SO isn't a platform for obtaining solutions to homework. Show some effort by letting us know what you've tried so far and posting your code. People can then help with debugging or point you in the direction of relevant resources. See this page for [how to create a minimal reproducible example.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

Using `find`

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

pattern=$2
folder=$1
export pattern

find "$folder" -type f -exec sh -c '
  for f; do
  if grep -q "$pattern" "$f"; then
    printf "%s is in %s\n" "$pattern" "$f"
  else
    printf "%s is not found in %s\n" "$pattern" "$f"
  fi
done' _ {} +
```

Howto use.

```
./myscript folder pattern
```